# Redirect old WordPress page to New Domain

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

I used to have a WordPress site on which I had certain pages.

One of those pages was;

http://example.com/make-website/

Now, I've deleted WordPress and placed a 'simple' one-page HTML site on the domain.

Do note, that the old page no longer exists because I deleted the WordPress install.

I want to redirect this old (WordPress) page to my new domain;

http://newexample.com/

The new site is a WordPress site, if that matters.

But I can't seem to manage to redirect it with this code in .htaccess;

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com/make-website/ http://newexample.com
```

Could anyone provide a solution for this, or point me to a solution?

I haven't been able to find it whilst I'm quite sure it should be here somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Make a file called `index.php` in the 'old location' with this content to redirect a user to another location:

Location of the file: `http://example.com/make-website/index.php`

Contents of the file:

```
<?php header('location:http://newexample.com'); ?>
```

This will send a HTTP redirect to the new location.

Comment: Apologies if this sounds dumb, but do I need to make a page on the old domain (HTML site now) with /make-website/?


Won't your answer re-direct the entire site to the new domain, instead of just one page to the new domain?

Comment: Updated my anser. It will redirect any user going to http://example.com/make-website/ to the new domain. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thank you very much Cagy79, this works exactly like I wanted and I've upvoted your response. Do you by any chance know if this method passes the 'link juice' from the old page to the new domain in order to gain something in SEO benefits?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple HTML file with a redirect in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://new-website.com'" />
```

I found this from https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/. It works for me.

Another way is to use JavaScript:

```
<script>
window.location.href = 'http://new-site.com/' + window.location.pathname
</script>
```

Comment: But that'd redirect the entire old site to the new domain, right?

Comment: In that case, you will need the JavaScript to help you. Something like: window.location.href = 'http://new-website.com' + path, where path is the relative one you extracted from the value of window.location.href.